# AKV10032: Invalid issuer error when connecting to Azure Key Vault from App Service

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

An API is deployed as an App Service on Azure. It connects to a Key Vault that is on the same subscription. An access policy was created for the App Service in the Key Vault. The App Service is configured with a system assigned identity. When the API attempts to access the key vault, the following error occurs:

> AKV10032: Invalid issuer. Expected one of https://sts.windows.net/b68456ea-cf3c-4835-9d30-a4b164f33190/, https://sts.windows.net/f8cdef31-a31e-4b4a-93e4-5f571e91255a/, https://sts.windows.net/e2d54eb5-3869-4f70-8578-dee5fc7331f4/, found [https://sts.windows.net/98de912a-48b9-4d1d-b5cd-21fd3f4f449d/.\](https://sts.windows.net/98de912a-48b9-4d1d-b5cd-21fd3f4f449d/.%5C)

*Edit:*
*I've removed a lot of content from this question as there was an error in it and I've been on the wrong track. Both the Key Vault and the App service do use the same tenant (contrary to my original post). The tenant Id is 98de912a-48b9-4d1d-b5cd-21fd3f4f449d, which is the one that is found in the error message above.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was happening because of a typo in the name of the key vault that I was given. Unfortunately the typo version was for an existing key vault, so we went on the wrong track investigating authorization problems.

Comment: I had the same issue though my key vault did not already exist. I think it's a bit of a false positive error message. Adjusted the name and go further.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, it was a guest account in Visual Studio. So only adding a tenant's account to Visual Studio works

Comment: I also had the same issue, signing in with the tenant's account solved it!

Comment: I have this problem and this approach 'solves' the issues, but unsatisfactorily. I want to use the non-tenanted account (which has lesser permissions, making it more secure).

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the Key Vault's AAD tenant.

If you use system-assigned managed identity on the App Service, it'll create a service principal in the same AAD tenant where the App Service is.
If the Key Vault and App Service are in the same subscription, they are under the same AAD tenant as well then.
You should be able to add that service principal to Key Vault access policies then and use it to access Key Vault.

If you have an app registration/service principal in another AAD tenant however, it cannot access the Key Vault.

Comment: I checked the Key Vault documentation and it does seem you can specify the tenantId during creation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keyvault/vaults/create-or-update#vaultproperties. I've never tried this but it could indicate a different tenant _can_ be used. The portal won't allow you to do this as far as I know, but if you use an ARM/Bicep template you could specify this.

Comment: Access policies also have a tenantId property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/keyvault/vaults/create-or-update#accesspolicyentry. If you try these and it works, let me know!

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I see that I was mistaken and the key vault and the app service are in fact using the same tenant. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Some of the answers here were spot on, I received it after trying to initially connect to a KeyVault that used "null" as the vault name appended into a formatted KeyVault uri.

If you're running into this issue, I recommend:

1. Validating that your KeyVault uri is being built / defined properly (all dynamic variables resolve).
2. That you validate that you're not using old versions of your Azure Dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I was signed into Visual Studio with more than one account. Even though the "correct" one was the active one, the error only went away after signing out with the other one.